# how to get specified rows from a csv file in python?

Tags: python, json, csv, object

I have tried this code to get specified rows from a csv file....

```
 import csv
 import json

 print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")


 with open("data.csv") as f:
       fieldnames = ("Nucleotide_Name","Ethnicity",
       "Disease_type_of_the_subject","Type_of_study")
       reader = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames)
       for row in reader:
             print(json.dumps(row))
```

my expected output is

```
 {"Nucleotide_change":39510,"Ethnicity:88qe78q,"Disease_type_of_the 
 _subject":"phnotype","type_of_study":"tramsmission"}
```

but its return all rows from that csv file...

```
{"Ethnicity": "Amino acid change", "Type_of_study": "Mutation type", 
"Disease type of the subject": "Nucleotide Change", "Nucleotide_Name": 
"Gene Location", "null": ["Functional prediction", "Ethnicity ", 
"Disease type of the subject", "Total number of subjects ", "Total 
number of subjects with specific mutaiton", "Control case", "Control 
case with specific mutation", "Disease association with Mutation", 
"Type of study", "Pubmed ID"]}
{"Ethnicity": "Leu", "Type_of_study": "Disease causing mutation", 
"Disease type of the subject": "c.1064_1076del", "Nucleotide_Name": 
"", "null": ["Premature truncation", "Caucasian (U.S./Spain)", "PCG", 
"7(families)", "2", "0", "0", "Associated with phenotype", "Family 
based", "27777502"]}
```

need some guidance..

Comment: (1) Avoid images, place a reasonable sample of output as properly formatted text in the question. (2) Explain or show what you expected in the question. (3) Fix the indentation of the code. It wouldn't run as shown.

Answer (score 0):

The  DictReader [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) says: *If a row has more fields than fieldnames, the remaining data is put in a list and stored with the fieldname specified by restkey (which defaults to None).*

```
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=['Nucleotide_Name','Ethnicity',
   'Disease_type_of_the_subject', 'Type_of_study'], restkey='ignored')
    for row in reader:
        row.pop('ignored', None)
        print(row)
```

By using the parameter "restkey" to aggregate all the fields you dont require and popping it out of your dictionary, you get the output you want.

Comment: @luv-its separate the four rows but the key-value  order was chaged...

Comment: What do you mean by order?

Comment: the original key value pair is {"Nucleotide_change":''delioshf","Ethnicity:"hi"}

Comment: but it returns {"Nucleotide:"hi","Ethnicity":"delioshf"}

Comment: Can you post 2 lines from the csv file?