# A row is not printed while using the DictReader to read a csv

Tags: python, csv

I have created a csv file as below:

```
%%writefile employee2.csv
name, department, birthday month
John Smith, Accounting, November, 6
Erica Meyers, IT, March
```

Now I want to read each row of the csv file with DictRead, but it doesn't read the second line (John Smith)

```
import csv
with open('employee2.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, restkey='day', skipinitialspace=True)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are: {", ".join(row)}')
        else:
            print(f'{row["name"]} works in the {row["department"]} department, and was born in {row["birthday month"]}.')
        line_count += 1
```

The output is:

```
Column names are: name, department, birthday month, day
Erica Meyers works in the IT department, and was born in March.
```

Now, I have two questions:
1- why it doesn't read the second line of the file and print it out?
2- What if I want to add the restkey to the print command, how can I do that?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `csv.DictReader`, it will read the `fieldnames` independently before you start reading the file by line, (`for row in csv_reader:`). There isn't a need to see if you are reading the first line (for `fieldnames`).

To add the `restkey` to the print, `pop` it off the row dictionary and then print the popped value. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61662841/how-to-get-specified-rows-from-a-csv-file-in-python/61673194#61673194).

```
import csv
with open('tmp1.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, restkey='day', skipinitialspace=True)
    cols = csv_reader.fieldnames
    print('Column names are: ', cols)
    for row in csv_reader:
        day = row.pop('day', None)
        if day != None:
            print(f'{row["name"]} works in the {row["department"]} department, and was born on {row["birthday month"]} {day[0]}.')
        else:
            print(f'{row["name"]} works in the {row["department"]} department, and was born in {row["birthday month"]}.')
```

Prints:

```
Column names are:  ['name', 'department', 'birthday month']
John Smith works in the Accounting department, and was born on November 6.
Erica Meyers works in the IT department, and was born in March.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.